# Generating a static constructor with all fields in Xamarin studio

Tags: c#, macos, code-generation, xamarin-studio

Pressing command+I on Mac OSX in Xamarin studio gives me 
the choice to create a constructor with all fields like so:

[image]

However, I don't see a way to make my own custom code generators like these. Xamarin studio has another way to generate code which is "Code Snippets", however, I can't find a way to get a parameter list using code snippets.

I am looking for a way to insert a template into my C# class which automatically lists all the local fields in order to make a static constructor. Does anyone know of a way?